# C# .NET vs. MySQL set time_zone for session

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

We have server in .NET (not ASP.NET) and use MySQL.
Is there a way how to set time_zone only for session?

For example in php, you can set time_zone in connection options.

Comment: _We have server in .NET (not ASP.NET)_ Hmm.. What? o.O

Comment: You have mixed up local and UTC values and assume that the way to fix this is to hard-code the timezone. It's not. Either types with offsets (eg DateTimeOffset in .NET and the equivalent in MySQL) or use UTC *everywhere* (in .NET *and* the database), ensuring all DateTime values have DateTimeKind.UTC. DateTimeOffset is the simpler solution

Comment: Perhaps this question should be reworded to "How to I overcome MySQL's missing timezone offsets"? What you ask for is MySQL's hack to account for the lack of a time type with offsets, which assumes that you'll never have to store times from different timezones. MySQL developers don't fly international it seems. .NET *does* have offsets (DateTimeOffset) so the easiest way would be to modify your code to convert `DateTime` values to `DateTimeOffset` with the same offset as the one used on the server

Comment: The other solution is to use UTC everywhere, especially in MySQL. Finding a better database is also a very good option. PostreSQL is far more reliable and has far better type support

Comment: We use utc everywhere (DateTime.UtcNow), but the os timezone has to be set to local time. MySql has type timestamp, which is stored in utc and displayed on client according timezone defined in their communication (global/session,...). The problem is, when I store utc time, the time is converted to utc twice: 1. DateTime.UtcNow itself and 2. because of server vs. MySql communication timezone - all times are treated as local times. I could use DateTime.Now, but then we would end up having problems during daylight saving. To store time in MySql as int is also not an option for us.